# toggle UIButton-state when pressing, like a switch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, togglebutton

```
-(void)setState:(id)sender
{
    UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
    BOOL buttonBool = ([button state]==selected : YES ? NO);
    [sender setSelected:buttonBool++];

}
```

this is my idea, but i cant figure out the actual state of the button calling the funktion.
any button, that calls this funktion, should be toggled between default and selected-state, so that it works like a switch. i just need to have own background-graphics, else i had used a switch.

so, can anyone please correct my idea ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this way:

```
-(void)setState:(id)sender
{
    UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
    button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```

Comment: oh.. that was too simple !
i think that this works, how i want it to work, thank you. i´ll try it tomorrow                               Message: You can accept an answer in 8 minutes  so tomorrow i´m going to accept this

Comment: Yeah, this is the **smart** way of programming +1 !

Comment: I don't understand why Apple didn't make this a built-in method for `UIButton`. It is such a common use case, and a simple `- (void)toggleSelected:(UIButton *)sender` would make things a bit easier for a lot of people. For anyone who has lots of buttons that need to be toggled in their application, it might make sense to create a category on `UIButton` called `UIButton+Toggle` or something, and extend UIButton to add this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 way:

```
func setState(button: UIButton) {
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
}
```

(Thanks to @nadi-hassan for the Swift 3 tip.)

Comment: swift 3 renamed "selected" to "isSelected"

Comment: Thanks @NadiHassan