# UIButtons as segmented controls

Tags: iphone, uibutton, custom-controls, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol

Having a segmented control with two UIButton and set the action to `action:@selector(segmentedControl:)` for each button.

```
    - (IBAction)segmentedControl:(id)sender {

        BOOL activateSecond = _firstTab.selected;
        _firstTab.selected = !activateSecond;
        _secondTab.selected = activateSecond;
}
```

The issue which still remains is how to solve if I'm tapping on the active button (now the active state jumps to the other one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of my head, I think you could use tag property.

Set each button's tag to a number.

Then when you receive a send in your segmentedControl method cast it to UIButton and check it's tag value.

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControl:(id)sender {

    int buttonTag = ((UIButton*)sender).tag;

    if(_firstTab.selected && buttonTag != 1){
       _firstTab.selected = NO;
       _secondTab.selected = YES;
    }else if(_secondTab.selected && buttonTag != 2){
       _firstTab.selected = YES;
       _secondTab.selected = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: One last issue... I have a two background images for two states `forState:UIControlStateSelected` and `forState:UIControlStateNormal`. How do I remove the for the normal one. If I'm holding down the active image background disappears until I'm releasing it...

Comment: Set the following: `[_firstTab setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"state_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_firstTab setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"state_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [_firstTab setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"state_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_firstTab setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"state_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];`

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of which button was previously selected and then you can catch when a new button is pressed via:

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControl:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl * myControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;

    if(myControl.selectedSegmentIndex != previouslySelectedIndex)
    {
        // here the user has selected a new button, which becomes the active one
        previouslySelectedIndex = myControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    } else {
        // the user tapped on the active, previously selected button
    }
}
```

Of course you'll need to initialize previouslySelectedIndex to start with.

Let me know if this idea helps you out.

Comment: [like his example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300534/toggle-uibutton-state-when-pressing-like-a-switch) but I have two UIButtons not a `UISegmentedControl`

Comment: Ahhh, your question could have been a bit more clear (I was confused by the words "segmented control").  A solution would still involve the sam concept -- you can still keep track of the active button state for both separate buttons.