# manage multiple pressed UIButtons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I have a uiviewcontroller with many UIButtons that are meant to be selected and kept pressed until touched on again. I define each button in the viewDidLoad and give all of them the same selector method (tapButton):

```
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ...
```

What I would like to do, is in the tabButton: method, to use the selector to determine which button was pressed, and then change its state with the following:

```
- (IBAction) tapButton:(id)sender
{
  if ( sender.selected ) {
    sender.highlighted = NO;
    sender.selected = NO;
} else {
    sender.highlighted = YES;
    sender.selected = YES;
}
}
```

You will notice that this is merely a pseuodo code since I can't really do "sender.selected" or "sender.highlighted" but thats what I am trying to accomplish.

is there any in way in which I can accomplish this? I would hate to create 30 "tapButton" methods (thats the number of UIButtons I have, yes...) for managing each UIButton's state.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why can't you do `sender.selected` or `sender.highlighted`?? They are valid...That's exactly what the sender argument is for (it is the button that was pressed)

Comment: I wish I could do that, but I am getting errors...this would have made my life so much easier!

Comment: "errors"...very descriptive of you.  Perhaps your question should be about those errors instead?  I toggle selected in this way all the time.

Comment: I actually found a bug: changed "id" to "UIButton" in the tabButton: method and no errors now, but it doesnt work like I expect. First tap on the button - the button flickers, second tap - nothing happens, then again, it flickers if I tap, etc. but it doesnt stayed "pressed"

Comment: Did you actually set it up to look different when it is selected?  If not, nothing will happen.  Also if you want it to stay "highlighted" you are going to have to delay your call to sender.highlighted or else it will be overridden (buttons unhighlight themselves when touches end).  The easiest way is to use `dispatch_after`.

Comment: Do I have to have another image for this state? Can't I make its "pressed state" like the color it gets when I tap on it?

Comment: Nope, the only things you can change automatically are title, title font color, title font shadow color, image, and background image.  Anything else must be done manually.

Comment: Did you already try the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300534/toggle-uibutton-state-when-pressing-like-a-switch

Comment: yes i did, but from some reason this trick never worked for me, and I just realized that what was missing was the image of the "pressed" state...now its all good. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `tag` of each button like this

```
button1.tag = 1;
button2.tag = 2;
....
```

Then in your selector

```
- (IBAction) tapButton:(id)sender
{
   switch((UIButton*)sender.tag){
     case 1:
     .....
   }
}
```

Comment: good idea, i like it, but was hoping to find something more "elegant"...+1 though.

Comment: Keep on finding if you get it, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton * selectedButton = [[UIButton allo]init];
/*for removing old highlight*/
selectedButton.higlighted = NO;
selectedButton = sender;
/*for setting new button highlight*/ sender.selected = YES
```

the above code will help you . Here am using new button to store last button state

Comment: This code makes no sense.  You should remove the first line, and use `self.selectedButton.highlighted = NO` on the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch case for this...or you can also implement this by using alpha property...

```
-(IBAction) tapButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if ([btn isSelected]) 
    {
        btn.selected = NO;
        btn.alpha = 0.5;
    } else {
        btn.selected = YES;
        btn.alpha = 1;
    }
}
```